# ANTLR4: Expected ID got ID

Tags: antlr4

Why ANTLR don't recognize the tokens correctly?
I think that the problem is something to do with the "MemberAccessor" has an ID and the "CustomMethodCall" rule too.

Grammar

```
**statement 
    : varDeclaration  
    | customMethodCall;
customMethodCall : (memberAccessor '.)? ID L_PAREN expressionList R_PAREN;

memberAcessorPart 
    : ID                            
    | 'this'
    | ID '.getAt' L_PAREN expression R_PAREN
    | ID arrayGet: 
    | ID L_PAREN expressionList R_PAREN;
memberAccessor 
    : memberAcessorPart (ACESSAR memberAcessorPart)*;
**

protected override void ReportNoViableAlternative (Parser recognizer, NoViableAltException e) {
        string[] expected = new String[e.GetExpectedTokens ().Count];
        int[] expectedInts = e.GetExpectedTokens ().ToArray ();
        for (int i = 0; i < expected.Length; i++) {
            if (expectedInts[i] == -1) expected[i] = "<EOF>";
            else expected[i] = PortuProParser.DefaultVocabulary.GetDisplayName (expectedInts[i]);

        }
        string c = PortuProParser.DefaultVocabulary.GetDisplayName (e.StartToken.Type);
        if (expected.ToList ().IndexOf (c) == -1)
            throw new PortuProException (e.StartToken.Line, e.StartToken.Column,  "Entrada desconhecida. '" + e.StartToken.Text + "'\n\nEsperado: '" + string.Join (", ", expected) + "'");

    }
```

Well i've got on 'c' the 'ID' and the 'ID' is expected as token.

Comment: In order for others to help you you should provide the used grammar as well as the input that causes the problem

Comment: Also, when you see token mismatch problems first print your token list (your common token stream can give you that) to see if the tokens are actually what you expect. Often it's a matter of wrong lexing that breaks the parser.

Comment: Sorry, i will put the grammar file